# Proving Properties of Boolean Algebras $(x+y) + (y\cdot x') = x+y$

Tags: proof-explanation, boolean-algebra

I'm trying to justify the following simplification:
$(x + y) + (y \cdot x') = x + y$

The solution that was provided to me is as follows:

$
= (x + y) + (y \cdot x') - (LHS)\\
= x + y \cdot (1 + x')\\
= x + y \cdot (1)\\
= x + y\\
$

I'm a little confused on the jump from steps 1 to 2, and what rule was applied and then also the switch from a disjunction to a conjunction.

Is anyone able to provide some insight into the reasoning?

Comment: I want to apologize for the unfriendly comment you received from another user below your most recent question.  I flagged the comment, and the comment was deleted.  I encourage you to undelete the post; I will upvote it.  It is clear you put effort into writing the post, and it deserves to be attended to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That step actually combines three steps. In order, they are associativity of disjunction, conjunctive identity, and distributivity of conjunction over disjunction:

$$\begin{align*}
(x+y)+(y\cdot x')&=x+\big(y+(y\cdot x')\big)\\
&=x+\big((y\cdot 1)+(y\cdot x')\big)\\
&=x+\big(y\cdot(1+x')\big)
\end{align*}$$

Then it just completes the calculation within the parentheses.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much for the quick and clear explanation.

Comment: @confundido: You’re very welcome.